# Desktop files now have a shortcut overlay after upgrading to Win 8.1

Tags: windows-8

I've just finished upgrading from Windows 8 to 8.1, and all of the files saved on my desktop (as well as any new files saved to my desktop) have a shortcut overlay.  Is there any way to undo this?  It's now impossible to distinguish between actual shortcuts and regular files.

[image]

Comment: Please post a picture of the overlay.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've added a screenshot.

Comment: run regedit.exe and go to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Icons** Look here for numbers and strings which pint to a DLL or ico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was apparently caused by a conflict between my backup software (Spideroak) and TortoiseSVN, and first appeared immediately after I upgraded from Win8 to Win8.1. For anyone experiencing the same issue, click the Preferences setting in Spideroak, then un-check the "Display File and Folder Overlay Icons" option and reboot.